# JQuery slideToggle with 50 divs

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use the slideToggle function on one div that's nested in another div but I have 50 different sets of div's that are this way

```
<div id="parent">
 #code...
<div id="child">
 #code...
</div>
</div>
```

What I want is a way to avoid writing 50 different slidetoggle functions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use context, i.e. `$(this)`. However, since you haven't provided enough information (e.g. what events you are listening to), it is hard to tell you how you should write your code.

Comment: I want to use a click event to accomplish this. Sorry I forgot to include that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since jQuery creates an Array of elements from the Selector Object, you need to refer to the `this` exact Element which triggered your function event and than you can go for other (child) selectors

<sub>P.S: *Don't* use duplicate ID, use `Class Selectors` instead:</sub>

```
$('.parent').on("yourEventHere", function(){

    $(this).find('.child').doSomething(); // or use:
    $('.child', this).doSomething();      // ".child", children of this

});
```

A practical example would be:

```
<div class="parent">
   1code...
   <div class="child">1code...</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
   2code...
   <div class="child">2code...</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
   3code...
   <div class="child">3code...</div>
</div>
```

```
$(".child").hide(); // Hide all children
$('.parent').on("click", function(){
    $('.child', this).toggle();
});
```

or using `.find()`:

```
$(".child").hide(); // Hide all children
$('.parent').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.child').fadeToggle();  
});
```

Comment: @PaulBulling PHP has nothing to do with JS. PHP Loop simply writes your articles inside the file at server-side. Than once that file arrives to the browser CSS and JS are here to do their job. Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net with an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like this and don't use ids use classes for repeating functions like this :)

```js
$('.parent').on('click', function() {
  $(this).find('.child').slideToggle();
});

// To prevent slide toggle if you click inside the child element
$('.child').on('click', function(e) {
  return false;
});
```

```css
.child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="parent">
  #code...parent
  <div class="child">
    #code...child
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  #code...parent
  <div class="child">
    #code...child
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  #code...parent
  <div class="child">
    #code...child
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  #code...parent
  <div class="child">
    #code...child
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  #code...parent
  <div class="child">
    #code...child
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  #code...parent
  <div class="child">
    #code...child
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  #code...parent
  <div class="child">
    #code...child
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  #code...parent
  <div class="child">
    #code...child
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  #code...parent
  <div class="child">
    #code...child
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  #code...parent
  <div class="child">
    #code...child
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  #code...parent
  <div class="child">
    #code...child
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  #code...parent
  <div class="child">
    #code...child
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why to misuse?  What do you mean with misuse return false?

Comment: cause you're at `e.stopPropagation();` not at `return`

Comment: In jquery return false does that and prevents the default event of the element.  I don't know why you think that it is misused :)

Comment: `return false` needs to be used with caution. That is because it prevents the execution of code that comes after it in the same block, and that it also prevents event bubbling — for it being the equivalent of `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()`